# Почему происходит утечка памяти?

Tags: c#, .net, сервер, сокет, память

Есть метод который делает скриншот экрана каждые 20 мс и отправляет его клиенту. Но после нескольких минут работы программа сжирает всю память, хотя вроде бы не должна. Где происходит утечка памяти?

```
private static async void Send(Socket handler)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    ImageSource image = ScreenCapture.CopyScreen();
                    byte[] message = ImageSourceToBytes(new JpegBitmapEncoder(), image);
                    handler.Send(message);
                    await Task.Delay(20);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Сервер: " + ex.Message);
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }
        });

    }
```

> Методы работы с изображениями:

```
public static byte[] ImageSourceToBytes(BitmapEncoder encoder, ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        var bitmapSource = imageSource as BitmapSource;

        if (bitmapSource != null)
        {
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Save(stream);
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }

 public static class ScreenCapture
{
    public static BitmapSource CopyScreen()
    {
        var left = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.X);
        var top = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.Y);
        var right = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.X + screen.Bounds.Width);
        var bottom = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.Y + screen.Bounds.Height);
        var width = right - left;
        var height = bottom - top;

        using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
            {
                bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));
                return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    screenBmp.GetHbitmap(),
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE.** Добавлен скриншот профайлера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: профилировщиком пробовали смотреть?

Comment: @Grundy, честно говоря без понятия что это. Это какой-то инструмент VS?

Comment: в том числе и в VS тоже есть, вот в [этом вопросе посмотрите](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/net-memory-profiling-tools)

Comment: @Grundy, Посмотрел. Профилировщик показывает что причина в `MemoryStream` , добавил скриншот. Хотя с ним проблем не должно быть, так как использую `using`/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проблема в том, что если вы вызываете функцию `Bitmap.GetHbitmap`, то вам [необходимо](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx#Anchor_2) вручную вызывать функцию `DeleteObject` из gdi32.dll для хэндлера, который вернула `GetHbitmap`. В противном случае действительно будет утечка.

Вот немного модифицированный класс `ScreenCapture`:

```
public class ScreenCapture : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    private IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
    private bool disposed;

    public BitmapSource CopyScreen()
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(ScreenCapture).FullName);

        var left = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.X);
        var top = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.Y);
        var right = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.X + screen.Bounds.Width);
        var bottom = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.Y + screen.Bounds.Height);
        var width = right - left;
        var height = bottom - top;

        using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)) {
            using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp)) {
                bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));
                hBitmap = screenBmp.GetHbitmap();
                return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!disposed) {
            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero) {
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Код отправки в сокет:

```
while (true)
{
    byte[] message = null;
    using (var capture = new ScreenCapture()) {
        ImageSource image = capture.CopyScreen();
        message = ImageSourceToBytes(new JpegBitmapEncoder(), image);
    }
    handler.Send(message);
    await Task.Delay(20);
}
```

Comment: Проблема решилась, спасибо!